# Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Tags: android, android-listview

I have created an xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list" >
</ListView>
```

and an activity:

```
public class ExampleActivity extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainlist);
    }
}
```

As you see, I have not done anything else. But I'am getting the error:

> Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Even though I have the `android:id="@+id/list"` line in my xml.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 348, accepted):

Rename the id of your ListView like this,

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Since you are using `ListActivity` your xml file must specify the keyword *android* while mentioning to a ID.

If you need a custom `ListView` then instead of Extending a `ListActivity`, you have to simply extend an `Activity` and should have the same id without the keyword *android*.

Comment: Doing this did fix my problem, thanks. But I wonder if you would be so kind as to write a few words of explanation as to when a ListView must have the ID "@android:id/list" and when it is OK for it to have an arbitrary name. It's because I like to not only fix my problem but also to understand why the fix was needed.

Comment: Works. But why this 'games' with id depending on the view impl?

Comment: When I add `@android`, Eclipse says `list cannot be resolved or is not a field`

Comment: same problem it shows error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@android:id/list_interestsent').

Comment: @RenniePet I believe this is because in the `@android` namespace android keeps many constants so it can implement classes like `ListActivity` which need to know which component is your `ListView` if you're using a custom layout.

Comment: I have replaced to  "MainActivity extends Activity" solved my issue. thanks

Comment: @id/android:list also seems to work, any thoughts on that?

Comment: Wondering the difference between `android:id="@+id/list"` and `android:id="@android:id/list"` Could it be possible that the latter one is referred to an existing android is called `list`?
But what's that?

Answer (score 23):

You should have one listview in your `mainlist.xml` file with id as `@android:id/list`

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 15):

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

this should solve your problem

Answer (score 8):

Exact way I fixed this based on feedback above since I couldn't get it to work at first:

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@android:id/list"
>
</ListView>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
```

preferences.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<PreferenceCategory
    android:key="upgradecategory"
    android:title="Upgrade" >
    <Preference
        android:key="download"
        android:title="Get OnCall Pager Pro"
        android:summary="Touch to download the Pro Version!" />
</PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 4):

Inherit **Activity** Class instead of **ListActivity** you can resolve this problem.

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity  {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.mainlist);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

One other thing that affected me: If you have multiple test devices, make sure you are making changes to the layout used by the device. In my case, I spent a while making changes to xmls in the "layout" directory until I discovered that my larger phone (which I switched to halfway through testing) was using xmls in the "layout-sw360dp" directory. Grrr!