# list view error android

Tags: android

this is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);

    final Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            while(i<30){
                String stringValue = Integer.toString(i);
            tt[i] = sendPostDataToInternet(stringValue);
            i++;
            }
            //TextView f=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cc);
            //f.setText(tt[1]+tt[2]+tt[3]);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(v.getContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, tt);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    });
       }
```

I tried to set the data to text and it worked, but when I set it into a listview it gives

```
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
```

whats the matter
Thanks.

Comment: Post the full logcat trace. And, [Do you've this in your main.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11050834/940096)

Comment: Are you extending simple activity or Listactivity

Comment: is there any error simply data not shown on screen issue ?

Comment: @DheereshSingh nope nope

Comment: @DheereshSingh i've shown the logcat lines

Comment: `ZygoteInit.java` is this your activity right

Comment: but there is no error in that.... have you getting force close dialog?

Comment: no .................Zygote is the part of android OS and used memory management in OS

Comment: @DheereshSingh yesyesyes

Comment: these are general log of the OS comes in every once log cat

Comment: @DheereshSingh but i got force close

Comment: have you tried use YOURActivityName.this instead of v.getContext()

Answer (score 1):

in line

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(v.getContext(),
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, tt);
```

use `YOURActivityName.this` instead of `v.getContext()`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `this` or `activity.this` or even `getActivity()` when you instantiate the adapter.

Since I use fragments a lot, I usually end up using `getActivity()` so I can reuse a fragment in more than one activity if necessary.

Example:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, tt);
```