# not running 1st activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

error occur on my first activity of application. Error is: "application stopped unexpectedly"

My first xml activity is visit_record.xml

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

I've created class for this activity is:
visit_record.java

```
public class visit_record extends ListActivity {
    static final String[] LIST = new String[] {"My Task", "Task Execution", "Non-Ticket Task"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.visit_record,LIST));

    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text

            Intent intent;
            switch (position) {
               case 0:
               intent= new Intent(visit_record.this, My_Task.class);
                startActivity(intent);
              break;
                case 1:
                    intent=new Intent(visit_record.this, task_execution.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    intent=new Intent(visit_record.this, non_ticket_task.class);
                    startActivity(intent);  
                    break;

                   default:
                    break;
            }}

    });
}}
```

Kindly guide me why it gives error and not run application in mobile phone.

Comment: please post your logcat error msg.

Comment: check your manifest file. use intent-filter for first activity.

Comment: i've added intent in manifest. but still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have extended ListActivity and when you do that your ListView must have the id `android:id="@android:id/list"`. You missed it.

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11050817/603744) for more details.

Comment: on error Log: keybinding conflict occur:( it still not resolve Andro. by add adding id:(

Comment: better post your logcat by editing your question. I can't get you.

Comment: it gives error "unable to start service intent if Etrack activity"    EtrackActivity is my another project. in this project no error occur except brightness or light errors