# OnitemClickListener not working

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I want `OnitemClickListener` for a `listview` but it doesn't work for me.it give Logcat error that.

**Your content must have a listview whose id attribute is `R.id.list`**

and my application do not launches . I uses sqlite in my project to store a number and display it in a `listview`.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" />
```

this code is for click ..

```
 ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "item clicked: ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Its already been answered many times here in stackOverflow. Have you done searching http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050817/your-content-must-have-a-listview-whose-id-attribute-is-android-r-id-list

Comment: @Androyds thanks for response. yes i have searched. now ** ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.);** doesnot show the list id. for 'android:id="@+id/android:list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `@+id/android:list` it might work then

Comment: i have checked your answer but in mainActivity its id is not accesible.