# your content must have a listview whose id attribute is ' android.r.id.list ' .

Tags: android, listview, runtime-error

I write the program but when i run this program, the program has runtime error :(

The error in LogCat is :

```
your content must have a listview whose id attribute is 'android.r.id.list'
```

I set `android:id="@android:id/list"` in `ListView` in activity_main.xml file.

I write my code, Please read this and help me .

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private TextView text;
private static final String[] items={"test", "test1" , "test2" , "test3" , "test4" , "test5" , "test6"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.row,R.id.label,items));
    text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);
}
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent,View v,int position,Long id){
    text.setText(items[position]);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/selection"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   <ListView
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@android:id/list"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

row.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/pic"
       android:padding="2dip"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:src="@drawable/pic"/>
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/label"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Cheers.

Comment: your code is working..... no issue..

Comment: you should really remove this line from  ListView `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Comment: @JonJafari if it doesn't works, Clean, build and then try

Comment: Thank for answers. I run the program again but the program not run. I clean and build again but the program not run ! Finally i create a new project in Eclipse and i copy my codes and paste in new project, the program run. What was the problem?  But when i clicked on the items of list, the program not shows selected item . Why? What is the problem?

Comment: Thanks. My problem solved and the program runs but i want to know why, when i create a new project in Eclipse the program runs true?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050817/your-content-must-have-a-listview-whose-id-attribute-is-android-r-id-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### compare your code nothing difference....

[image]

mainActivity

```
package com.example.testdemo;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private TextView text;
    private static final String[] items = { "test", "test1", "test2", "test3",
            "test4", "test5", "test6" };

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_);



        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.lable,
                R.id.label, items));
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selection);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        text.setText("" + items[position]);
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }


    }
}
```

---

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selection"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView

        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

Please extend Activity instead of ListActivity,

Then get its view from layout file

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

Then call `listView.setAdapter(/*agruments*/);` method

instead of calling setListAdapter().

Answer (score 2):

you have to get the instance of a listview like

```
ListView lv=getListView();
```

Answer (score -3):

Change this line

```
 android:id="@android:id/list"
```

to

```
 android:id="@+id/list"
```