# Custom adapter error ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Tags: android, xml, android-listview, android-adapter

I know this has been asked a lot and most answers simply state to modify xml file to

```
<ListView
  android:id="@android:id/list"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

but I'm still getting the error `ListView` whose id attribute is `android.R.id.list`

My code loads stuff from a local db and returns it as a ListView, see my code below:

```
public class PrepopSqliteDbActivity extends ListActivity {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "yourdb.sqlite3";
    //������� ��������� �������� ������� ���� ����� �� �����������
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "friends";
    private static final String FRIEND_ID = "_id";
    private static final String FRIEND_NAME = "name";
    private static final String FRIEND_GAME = "game";
    public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {FRIEND_ID, FRIEND_NAME, FRIEND_GAME};

    private SQLiteDatabase database;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //��� �������� ������
        ExternalDbOpenHelper dbOpenHelper = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(this, DB_NAME);
        database = dbOpenHelper.openDataBase();
        //���, ���� �������!
        populateListViewFromDB();

    }

    private void populateListViewFromDB() {
        Cursor cursor = getAllRows();

        // Allow activity to manage lifetime of the cursor.
        // DEPRECATED! Runs on the UI thread, OK for small/short queries.
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        // Setup mapping from cursor to view fields:
        String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] 
                {FRIEND_ID, FRIEND_NAME, FRIEND_GAME, };
        int[] toViewIDs = new int[]
                {    R.id.item_icon,   R.id.item_name,        R.id.item_game};

        // Create adapter to may columns of the DB onto elemesnt in the UI.
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = 
                new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                        this,       // Context
                        R.layout.item_layout,   // Row layout template
                        cursor,                 // cursor (set of DB records to map)
                        fromFieldNames,         // DB Column names
                        toViewIDs               // View IDs to put information in
                        );

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
    }
    public Cursor getAllRows() {
        String where = null;
        Cursor c =  database.query(true, TABLE_NAME, ALL_KEYS, 
                            where, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }
```

the xml file `activity_main.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:paddingRight="8dp">

<ListView
  android:id="@android:id/list"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView> 

</LinearLayout>
```

and `item_layout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxHeight="80dp"
        android:maxWidth="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="NAME!"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_game"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_name"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Let me know your suggestions, all answers are appreciated!!

logcat error:

```
12-25 18:12:20.319: E/AndroidRuntime(902): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-25 18:12:20.319: E/AndroidRuntime(902): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.softeq.android.prepopdb/com.softeq.prepopdb.activity.PrepopSqliteDbActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
12-25 18:12:20.319: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
12-25 18:12:20.319: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
12-25 18:12:20.319: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-25 18:12:20.319: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
12-25 18:12:20.319: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-25 18:12:20.319: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-25 18:12:20.319: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-25 18:12:20.319: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-25 18:12:20.319: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-25 18:12:20.319: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-25 18:12:20.319: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-25 18:12:20.319: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-25 18:12:20.319: E/AndroidRuntime(902): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
12-25 18:12:20.319: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
12-25 18:12:20.319: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
12-25 18:12:20.319: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
12-25 18:12:20.319: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at com.softeq.prepopdb.activity.PrepopSqliteDbActivity.onCreate(PrepopSqliteDbActivity.java:35)
12-25 18:12:20.319: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
12-25 18:12:20.319: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-25 18:12:20.319: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
12-25 18:12:20.319: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: can you pass the logcat error

Comment: added the log cat error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must to remove the implements `ListActivity` and create your class as an `Activity`. After this, you just have to change your `id` of your `ListView` in your xml file by **listview**:

> **android:id="@+id/listview"**

Like you tried to find it (`findViewById`) in your class.

---

This problem happens because you try to get a `ListView` with two different ways.

- You try to implements `ListActivity`, which need **only one** `ListView` with the **android:list** id and set to an adapter by `setListAdapter`.
- And you also try to have your `ListView` set to your adapter by `setAdapter` method.

So, keep the implement method and use the normal way to have a `ListActivity` (look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16081025/2668136) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html#Example)) **OR** change your implement by `Activity` and use a custom `ListView`.
This is resumed here: [RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11296367/2668136)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change your listview id to

```
<ListView
  android:id="@+id/listview"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: doesn't help 
gives the same error. I tried many variations, doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the listview as `android.R.id.list`, but then in the code as `R.id.listview`. In the xml, its called @android:id/list. Use`R.id.list` in your code and add the + to the xml id.