# content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Tags: android, listview, exception, android-listview

```
02-13 05:29:12.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1374): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-13 05:29:12.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1374): Process: net.multiplesystem.nosms, PID: 1374
02-13 05:29:12.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1374): java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
02-13 05:29:12.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:344)
02-13 05:29:12.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:145)
02-13 05:29:12.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:941)
02-13 05:29:12.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
02-13 05:29:12.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
02-13 05:29:12.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
02-13 05:29:12.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
02-13 05:29:12.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
02-13 05:29:12.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
02-13 05:29:12.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
02-13 05:29:12.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
02-13 05:29:12.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
02-13 05:29:12.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
02-13 05:29:12.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-13 05:29:12.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
02-13 05:29:12.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
02-13 05:29:12.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
02-13 05:29:12.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
02-13 05:29:12.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
02-13 05:29:12.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-13 05:29:12.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2289)
02-13 05:29:12.454: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

JAVA

```
public class UserDetails extends ListFragment  {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayList<String> userIndex = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.users_tab, container, false);   
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(inflater.getContext(),R.layout.single_user_chat_tab,userIndex);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        return android;
    }
}
```

When i execute the program it show the run time exception. But i all-ready have listview with id list. I have no idea why it shows the exception. please guide me friends why it throws the exception.I have tried all the solution but still get the same problem.

Comment: Post your `ListFragment` too.

Comment: did you try to clean and rebuild the project?

Comment: Post your code and XML

Comment: yes i tried all the alternate.

Comment: Is `users_tab.xml` the layout that you have pasted here?

Comment: any idea apoorv why it throws the exception ?

Comment: Sorry, no idea everything seems to be the way it should be.

Comment: yes that's why m confused too. Firstly It was working fine but then this happens :(

Comment: Learn to search, Learner.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907122/java-lang-runtimeexception-your-content-must-have-a-listview-whose-id-attribute?rq=1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647831/android-your-content-must-have-a-listview-whose-id-attribute-is-android-r-id-li?rq=1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080466/your-content-must-have-a-listview-whose-id-attribute-is-android-r-id-list?rq=1

Comment: @Drive i have search a lot but couldn't find the solution.That is why i posted it.Instead of down vote please solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can call setListAdapter before returning your custom View in the onCreateView. I see 3 solutions

1. Either call super.onCreateView() instead of inflating
2. Either set your adapter in OnActivityCreated
3. Either write android.findViewById(android.R.id.list).setAdapter(adapter); instead

Comment: even if i removed the adapter still shows same exception.

Comment: So the easy way to go around the problem: Just implement simple Fragment, the list fragment does not bring real convenience.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: not working. My activity class extends ListFragment.

Comment: @AndroidLearner check now, Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html

Comment: When using ListActivity or ListFragment, we must have a ListView in our layout xml whose id is = @id/android:list. Since ListActivity and ListFragment internally use this id to create a list and this is the list which is referred or returned by getListView().