# ListActivity return error

Tags: android, listactivity

what need with ListActivity on this code that not return "unfortunately,app has stopped"

& please dont NAY!

```
package com.example.app;

Imports............

public class Main extends ListActivity 
{

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v,
        int position, long id)
 { }

}
```

> > >
> >     09-12 00:52:51.373: D/AndroidRuntime(1871): Shutting down VM
> >     09-12 00:52:51.373: W/dalvikvm(1871): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
> >     09-12 00:52:51.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1871): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> >     09-12 00:52:51.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1871): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.rss/com.example.rss.Main}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
> >     09-12 00:52:51.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
> >     09-12 00:52:51.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
> >     09-12 00:52:51.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
> >     09-12 00:52:51.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
> >     09-12 00:52:51.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> >     09-12 00:52:51.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
> >     09-12 00:52:51.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
> >     09-12 00:52:51.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> >     09-12 00:52:51.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
> >     09-12 00:52:51.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
> >     09-12 00:52:51.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
> >     09-12 00:52:51.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> >     09-12 00:52:51.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1871): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
> >     09-12 00:52:51.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
> >     09-12 00:52:51.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:254)
> >     09-12 00:52:51.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
> >     09-12 00:52:51.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at com.example.rss.Main.onCreate(Main.java:26)
> >     09-12 00:52:51.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
> >     09-12 00:52:51.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
> >     09-12 00:52:51.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
> >     09-12 00:52:51.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     ... 11 more

Comment: check the logcat, you will know what is the error.. or just put logcat here..

Comment: please post your log.

Comment: read your stacktrace (I bet you don't have a android.R.id.list element in your layout)

Comment: logcat added to end of code

Comment: No - I have a List view with this name "@+id/lst_main"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050817/your-content-must-have-a-listview-whose-id-attribute-is-android-r-id-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are extending ListActivity you need to have an Listview with `android:id="@android:id/list"`.

if you want to use `@+id/lst_main`then dont extend ListActivity, just extended Activity.

Also you need to inflate the listview using the adapter

Comment: so what is different between ListActivity & Activity?

Comment: ListActivity makes it simple to create an activity whose main purpose is to show a list of elements. You can extend Activity and achieve the same thing but ListActivity makes it easier to achieve.  But when you are extending ListActivity you need to define one listview with id=@android:id/list.. It means you are using the android resource(default) list.

Comment: for a rss reader app which is better? ListActivity or Activity?

Comment: meanwhile i change my kist view name to @+id/lst_main , but i return error yet!

Comment: Depends on your requirement. if you are planning to have only listview in an activity go with listactivity, so that you will have more options for list.

Comment: if you want to use @+id/lst_main then dont extend ListActivity, just extended Activity.

Comment: Sorry my purpose was android:id/list - i change list view name to "@+id/list" but it yet return error - no need to Manipulation manifest

Comment: sorry again - my mean was this @+id/list

Comment: in your xml file replace your existing listview with this
 <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

Comment: Ok - The problem solved -i should change it in xml no in Design environment.

Comment: a Other question - do u work with rss readers or make once of them!?

Comment: I didn't get your question. could you re-frame it?

Comment: ok - at first thanx for your help- then i wanna create a ree reader - do you work with them or make a rss reader app!?

Comment: i haven't worked with it. you already have so many app, y still you want to make it?

Comment: my problem is with java coding & android abt Environment - i was work with c  - c++ and c# - but with java no!

Comment: can i ask u my question directly!!?

Comment: Sure. But it is better to post, so that sometimes you may get better solutions then me.

Comment: in this site we can not send message directly?

Comment: I dont think so. n i don't have idea on that bro. you are from which location?

Comment: fine.. you can notify me, by using @beginner after asking question. surely i will respond if i am available:)

Comment: very very tanx my BRO!

Answer (score 0):

You must set attribute to your ListView

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Also don't forget to register your Activity in manifest