# listactivity within an activity is not working(Android)

Tags: android, android-listview

ok it seems messy

i figured out a way

just teel me that when i call the **setonitemclicklistner()** it did fired overdirive method?

```
   getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

       //i couldn't reach here nor it shows this method

    }
  });
```

help :/

Comment: specify the error pls

Answer (score 0):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050817/your-content-must-have-a-listview-whose-id-attribute-is-android-r-id-list).

Your layout listview_for_customlist.xml must contain a ListView like this one:

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Check this line:

```
 list= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_for_custom_list);
```

You are using a different id, the ListView id of a ListActivity must be android.R.id.list

Comment: Please, show your layout. Check if the id is exactly @android:id/list

Answer (score 0):

When you change your `Activity` to `ListActivity` you don't need to `findViewById` for the `ListView` that has id as `list`.

You can just write

```
getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
```

In your layout change the id for the `ListView` to `android.id="@android:id/list"` and use `getListView` inside your activity to refer to this list view.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the id of your ListView to use the built in android list id @android:id/list

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Be sure that the id is exactly the same as above.

Then you can get the ListView by doing this

```
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```