# android listview error while moving from one screen to another

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview

Hi I am working on populating a ListView with an arraylist in Android, after clicking on a button to move from the first screen to the second. But after clicking on the first screen the following error appears. Any help is really appreciated.

second_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
android:id="@+id/listDisplayData"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

SecondActivity.java

package com.example.listexample;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

ListView listDisplayData;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

        //reference to listview
        ListView listDisplayData = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listDisplayData);

        final ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
        arr.add("name");
        arr.add("address");

        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.list_content, arr);

        listDisplayData.setAdapter(adapter);
 };
}
```

Error:

```
01-13 16:11:37.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1188): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-13 16:11:37.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1188): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.listexample/com.example.listexample.DisplayData}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
01-13 16:11:37.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-13 16:11:37.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-13 16:11:37.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-13 16:11:37.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-13 16:11:37.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-13 16:11:37.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-13 16:11:37.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-13 16:11:37.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 16:11:37.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-13 16:11:37.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-13 16:11:37.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-13 16:11:37.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-13 16:11:37.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1188): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
01-13 16:11:37.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
01-13 16:11:37.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:273)
01-13 16:11:37.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
01-13 16:11:37.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at com.example.listexample.DisplayData.onCreate(DisplayData.java:26)
01-13 16:11:37.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-13 16:11:37.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-13 16:11:37.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-13 16:11:37.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     ... 11 more
```

If any more detail is required then please let me know.

Comment: what don't you understand ? `Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'`

Comment: also, please read your error. it is on DisplayData, not on SecondActivity...

Comment: You have another activity which extends ListView but doesn't have android.R.id.list as id !  Your secondActivity is fine

Answer (score 1):

The `Exception` is telling you that your `ListView` needs to have `android.R.id.list` as an id. This is typically happens if you are creating your own layout for a `ListActivity` or `ListFragment`. Both of these require that you have a `ListView` with that id so you can make use of the convenience methods provided by each of these classes among other things.

The `Exception` is thrown by the `DisplayData` class not `SecondActivity`. I am quite sure that you are using either a `ListFragment` or `ListActivity` there.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error was the one simply shown in the error message.

```
Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

Rename the id of your ListView like this,

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11050829/1831275) for more information