# App crashes when retrieving data from mysql into listview

Tags: android, mysql, listview

I am trying to retrieve data from mysql and load into listview.But the app crashes when I try to run it.I am not able to solve the errors.The JSON response is working fine and the results are displayed in the browser.Please help.This is the MainActivity file

```
    package com.example.triallistview;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.net.ParseException;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
int ct_id;
String[] ct_name = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    ListView lv;
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    // http post
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/example/city.php");
       // httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
    }
    // convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
        String line = "0";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    // paring data
    JSONArray jArray;
    try {
        jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject json_data = null;
        ct_name = new String[jArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            ct_id = json_data.getInt("CITY_ID");
            ct_name[i] = json_data.getString("CITY_NAME");
        }
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No City Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


    lv = getListView();
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ct_name));
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(int  position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    ct_name[position] + " wasClicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


    });
    }
     }
```

The logcat looks like this

```
    03-25 02:42:03.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2380): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-25 02:42:03.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2380): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.triallistview/com.example.triallistview.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
    03-25 02:42:03.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
    03-25 02:42:03.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
    03-25 02:42:03.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    03-25 02:42:03.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
    03-25 02:42:03.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    03-25 02:42:03.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    03-25 02:42:03.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    03-25 02:42:03.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-25 02:42:03.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    03-25 02:42:03.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    03-25 02:42:03.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    03-25 02:42:03.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-25 02:42:03.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2380): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
    03-25 02:42:03.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     at  android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
    03-25 02:42:03.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
    03-25 02:42:03.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
    03-25 02:42:03.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     at com.example.triallistview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
    03-25 02:42:03.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
    03-25 02:42:03.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    03-25 02:42:03.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
    03-25 02:42:03.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):     ... 11 more
```

Please suggest me what changes should I do.

Comment: Why are you making a http request/web service call in onCreate Method? Use a AsynTask or Thread.

Comment: listview findviewbyid prob... look it once again. and try to use it in oncreate()

Answer (score 3):

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a
>   ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

You have

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
```

And then

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

So you need to have a ListView in `activity_main.xml` with id as below

```
<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Also remove

```
lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
```

You can use `lv = getListView()`

Quoting docs

> ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single,
>   full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire,
>   you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout
>   with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST
>   contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if
>   it's in code)

Apart of all these you are doing Network operation on the main ui thread. You need to use a `Thread` or `AsyncTask`.

```
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/example/city.php");
 // httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); // must be in a thread
```

You will get `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a
>   networking operation on its main thread.
>
> This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or
>   higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do
>   networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily
>   discouraged

Edit:

Seems there is lot of confusion. People want more accurate answer. SO i will post an example

Example:

In the below we have a `TextView` and a `ListView`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.testall.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="Static TextView" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

Here `MainActivity` extends `ListActivity` and you have `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`. `activity_main.xml` has other views apart from listview.

So you need a listview with id `android:id="@android:id/list"` in your xml

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    String[] array ={"A","B","C","D","E"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView lv = getListView();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

Snap

See the snap it has a static textview.

[image]

Now i changed the id as below. I still had the `TextView` in my layout nothing else changed

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
```

App crashes

```
 03-25 04:16:02.022: E/AndroidRuntime(1275): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

Well if people still don't understand and say its not clear and downvote they should mention the reason in the comment. I will be happy to edit.

If you don't want any other views other then the default list displayed there is no need for `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`. For example.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    String[] array ={"A","B","C","D","E"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

In the above there are no other views except the default list displayed.

Comment: I have added the id attribute for listview in activity_main.xml file.But still i am getting the error

Comment: @sheetal do have `<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"` in your `activtiy_main.xml`??

Comment: I have <ListView android:id="@+id/list"

Comment: @sheetal its not the same as `android:id="@android:id/list"`

Comment: @sheetal do check the edit. I have posted an example. Apart of that you are running network operation on the main ui thread which is wrong

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ListActivity then your layout must have ListView which id is `@android:id/list`

Change your `ListView` in `activity_main.xml`

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

You can also use

```
lv = getListView();
```

instead of

```
lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

Rename the id of your ListView like below,

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    .
    .
```

For more Reference [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050817/your-content-must-have-a-listview-whose-id-attribute-is-android-r-id-list)

Do your `ListView` initialize like below

```
ListView lv = getListView();
```