# Error when starting activity

Tags: android, android-listview

I've got an activity which is formed by four buttons. When I click one of them I go to another activity. All the buttons work well, but when I click the fourth the app stops. The activity must be started is formed by a ListView. Here is the code of that activity:

```
public class InformationActivity extends ListActivity {

String[] elements = {"About", "Rate"};

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     setContentView(R.layout.information_layout); 
     ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.optionslist);
     listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, elements));
 }

public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {

    if ("About".equals(elements[position]))
        {Intent i = new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);}
    else if ("Rate".equals(elements[position]))
        {Intent i = new Intent(this, FeedbackActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);}
    }
```

}

Checking the LogCat, I find the following error:

```
08-22 12:34:57.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1361): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.isa.gestordecurso/com.isa.gestordecurso.InformationActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

I don't understand the error. The id of the ListView in the XML is optionslist, which is defined in the Activity.

Hope there's a solution: Thanks!

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11050829/1137118

Comment: @Pphoenix, please flag as duplicate if you haven't yet.

Answer (score 1):

The fourth activity is a ListActivity, the list activity take default id for list view as `@android:id/list`, that is why it is saying

```
Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

You should use following id for list view **=>**`@android:id/list`

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#00FF00"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>`
```

For more on ListActivity, Read Developer Android [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm able to go to the list, but I don't understand why I can't start the activities os the items selected

Comment: what is the error ??logcat

Comment: There is no error now. I click one of the items of the list an the activity is not dislayed.

Comment: try `"About".equalsIgnoreCase(elements[position])`

Comment: print the value of `elements[position]`, my guess is you have not set on list click listener for list view

Comment: Should not use setOnItemClickListener?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59821/discussion-between-akhil-jain-and-isaias).