# ListView Prevented my app to show out

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm just a newbie on creating android app. I don't know what's going on to my app and I have been struggling for few days to find out the root causes. Can anyone help me out? 
The problem I facing is my app always been shut down when I proceed to xml which has item in the ListView.

Here's my code. Please help me out, I appreciate your time. Thanks in advance.

```js
***MainActivity.java***

package com.training_listview.win7.listview_seperate;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView MainActivity_LV = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.Main_ListView);

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, generateData());


        MainActivity_LV.setAdapter(adapter);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }


    private ArrayList<Item> generateData()
    {
        ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        items.add(new Item("Item 1","yes"));
        items.add(new Item("Item 2","No"));
        items.add(new Item("Item 3","Yes"));

        return items;
    }

}
```

```js
***MyAdapter.java***


package com.training_listview.win7.listview_seperate;


import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item>
{
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Item> itemsArrayList;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> itemsArrayList)
    {

        super(context, R.layout.item_list, itemsArrayList);

        this.context = context;
        this.itemsArrayList = itemsArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        // 1. Create inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // 2. Get rowView from inflater
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);

        // 3. Get the two text view from the rowView
        TextView labelView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ActivityName);
        TextView valueView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ActivityStatus);

        // 4. Set the text for textView
        labelView.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getName());
        valueView.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getStatus());

        // 5. return rowView
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

```js
***Item.java***

package com.training_listview.win7.listview_seperate;

public class Item
{
    private String name;
    private String status;


    public Item(String name, String status)
    {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.status = status;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getStatus()
    {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status)
    {
        this.status = status;
    }

}
```

```js
***item_list.xml***


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ActivityName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ActivityStatus"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

```js
***activity_main.xml***

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Main_ListView"
     />
</RelativeLayout>
```

```js
***AndroidManifest.xml***

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.training_listview.win7.listview_seperate" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

```js
***Logcat***


01-24 13:59:30.711    1927-1927/com.training_listview.win7.listview_seperate E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.training_listview.win7.listview_seperate, PID: 1927
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.training_listview.win7.listview_seperate/com.training_listview.win7.listview_seperate.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
            at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:381)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
            at com.training_listview.win7.listview_seperate.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Always start with the exception stacktrace. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Use Logcat for getting some traces as welll

Comment: Hi, @TrebiaProject.
I read through the logcat and i found this
"Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list' "
Is it I declare it wrongly?

Comment: Hi, @laalto thanks for your time. I read through the logcat and i found this "Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list' " Is it I declare it wrongly?

Comment: Could you tell me which is you line 15 on you activity MainActivity.java?

Comment: @TrebiaProject. this is the line on my MainActivity.java    " setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListActivity already has a listView with a id `android.R.id.list`.You should use `getListView` to access ListView.You can change you code in Java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    //get listView
    ListView MainActivity_LV = getListView();

    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, generateData());


    MainActivity_LV.setAdapter(adapter);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

or change you code in layout.xml

```
    ***activity_main.xml***

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help, I changed to what you wrote but I still having the same problem. :(

Comment: This is not going to work you need first to setContentView before getting the list view. Which xml will be followed?

Comment: ListActivity already had a ListView which's id is `android.R.id.list` so you do not need to `setContentView`.If you want to use `setContentView`,edit in you layout,you must add a ListView with id `android.R.id.list`

Comment: @TrebiaProject. Without the setContentView, the item_list.xml will be followed.

Comment: See my proposal, the problem is not setContentView is your layout.

Comment: @baitouwei Thanks to you too! I had been struggling for few days because of this! It's work perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

Now is clear and a duplicated issue ([Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050817/your-content-must-have-a-listview-whose-id-attribute-is-android-r-id-list)), as you are using a ListActivity the name of your list needs to be specific. In your layout activity_main.xml just change the following in the id of your list:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
 />
```

Comment: Omg, it's working!
 
Thanks a lot! I have been struggling few days because of this! Thanks to you, I had learned about the ListActivity and LogCat.