# Android: Navigation drawer and ListActivity

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer, listactivity, pdfviewer

Hi I want to introduce a navigation drawer in my Android app. In my activity I load pdf file in a list, this is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    private ListView mainListView ;  
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;  

    String filepath;

        String[] pdflist;
        File[] imagelist;


    //for navigation drawer
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    protected RelativeLayout _completeLayout, _activityLayout;
    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;


    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer);   //for navigation drawer


         final File storage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

            File images = new File(storage,"/Folder/");
            imagelist = images.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
                public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                    return ((name.endsWith(".pdf")));
                }
            });
            pdflist = new String[imagelist.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < imagelist.length; i++) {
                pdflist[i] = imagelist[i].getName();
            }
            this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pdflist));


//for navigation drawer

        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items); // load
        // titles
        // from
        // strings.xml

        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);// load icons from
        //strings.xml

        set(navMenuTitles, navMenuIcons);
        }



    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
            String path = imagelist[(int) id].getAbsolutePath();
            openPdfIntent(path);
        }

        private void openPdfIntent(String path) {
            try {
                final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, path);
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


//for navigation drawer
    public void set(String[] navMenuTitles, TypedArray navMenuIcons) {
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        //mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items
        if (navMenuIcons == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < navMenuTitles.length; i++) {
                navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[i]));
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < navMenuTitles.length; i++) {
                navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[i],
                        navMenuIcons.getResourceId(i, -1)));
            }
        }

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        // getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, // nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for
                // accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for
        // accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    }

    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /***
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
/*  @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        // boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        // menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();// finishes the current activity
            break;
        case 1:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            finish();// finishes the current activity
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

File drawer.xml is:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <!-- Add content here -->

        <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
                />

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#e5e5e5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#d6d6d6"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout/>
```

My doesn't work, I have the error `"Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is android.R.id.list".`
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050817/your-content-must-have-a-listview-whose-id-attribute-is-android-r-id-list)

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,please set your xml 
you can try it.
and the usage is not the great better.
you can try the user-defined adapter.

Comment: <listview    android:id="@+id/android.R.id.list"/> try it

Answer (score 0):

The `ListActivity` uses a `ListView` with the default id "android.R.id.list", retrieve this default id in your XML `ListView` using "@android:id/list".

Use this XML code:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    />
```