# “Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is android.R.id.list” on Xamarin for Visual Studio

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin.android

I'm developing a small Xamarin App.I am having trouble with this error on Xamarin for VS. I've tried to recreate this in a different project. I have already tried this solution [Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050817/your-content-must-have-a-listview-whose-id-attribute-is-android-r-id-list), its all over the Internet - and I'm starting to think its only applicable to Android Java Applications. When I change the id to android:id="@android:id/list i get the following error: Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0117  'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'list'

Android documentation wasn't very helpful either - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html. 
I'm fairly new to Android and Xamarin Dev.

Here's my AXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myDrawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txText"
            android:text="Hey slide from left of right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/leftListView"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#D2D2D2"
        android:dividerHeight="24dp"
        android:background="#F2F2F2" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here's my cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Support.V4.Widget;
public class WelcomeActivity : ListActivity
    {
        DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
        List<string> menuItemsLeft = new List<string>();
        ArrayAdapter mLeftAdapter;
        ListView mLeftDrawer;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Create your application here
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Generics);

            mDrawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.myDrawer);
            mLeftDrawer = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.list);
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: problem for `ListActivity`

Comment: okay, so is it a known problem @IntelliJAmiya...?

Comment: yes .You are using `android:id="@+id/leftListView"` for your listview

Comment: if it was `ListActivity` then you can use `android:id="@android:id/list"`

Answer (score 0):

change your listview id

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/leftListView"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#D2D2D2"
    android:dividerHeight="24dp"
    android:background="#F2F2F2" />
```

To

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#D2D2D2"
    android:dividerHeight="24dp"
    android:background="#F2F2F2" />
```

Comment: what should i change it to @vishal senjaliya...?

Comment: use your listview id @android:id/list

Comment: if you are using @android:id/list no need to create this mLeftDrawer = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.list); and I suggest you have to declare you arrayadapter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using default adapter for your `ListView` , then you have to define the id for the listView to `android:id="@android:id/list"`, so, change your listview to this:

```
<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list" //id changed
android:layout_width="240dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="left"
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
android:divider="#D2D2D2"
android:dividerHeight="24dp"
android:background="#F2F2F2" />
```