# Error "Cannot resolve symbol 'listView'" for a CustomListAdapter

Tags: android, listview

I am currently working on a basic custom ListAdapater.
On my MainActivity, it shows this error when trying to find my ListView from my XML file.

Here is my MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    ListView list;

    String[] itemName = {
            "Item 1",
            "Item 2",
            "Item 3"
    };
    String [] itemContent = {
            "Item Content 1",
            "Item Content 2",
            "Item Content 3"
    };

    Integer[] imageId = {
            R.mipmap.pic1,
            R.mipmap.pic2,
            R.mipmap.pic3,
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, itemName, itemContent, imageId);
        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                String SelectedItem = itemName[+position];
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), SelectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I actually had a different error before for this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050817/your-content-must-have-a-listview-whose-id-attribute-is-android-r-id-list).
My code showed completely fine apart from the error with the `android:id`, and this fixed this particular issue, but I now have the error with the `R.id.list`.

I also tried the suggestion of just Activity and dropping the keyword `android` in the XML.
Also fixed my old error but not this one.
I have just posted my original code however.

Comment: Try `android:id="@+id/list"` instead of `android:id="@android:id/list"` the `+` symbol matters.

Comment: Do not use `ListActivity` anymore!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `findViewById` line isn't completely necessary in a `ListActivity`

```
list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
```

It can instead be gotten with `getListView()`, or you can do that manually

```
list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Basically, your XML is using `android.R.id.list`, and not `R.id.list`. There's a difference.

If you see the error that `ListView` cannot be resolved, then you are missing an `import` statement.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sourav noted in above code that you didn't add **+** sign into         android:id="@android:id/list". By adding **+** sign into id means **you are giving 
( Assigning )new ID to that element** but without **+** means you are refer some other ID which is already declared somewhere else in your code

Comment: `@android:id/list` is a pre-defined ID, it does not need a plus

Comment: Thanks for getting back, but it does not work with or without the + sign.