# How to put ListView and TextView in the same layout in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to put `ListView` and `TextView` in same layout and I managed to do so but on executing the application I got some errors.
    Below is the xml code
    `

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvCourses"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="40" >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="60"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHOD"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:text="Output here" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the JAVA code

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.teacher);
    Courses = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvCourses);
    Output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHOD);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,      Names);
    Courses.setAdapter(adapter);
    Courses.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

    Output.setText(HOD[arg2]);

}
```

[Here is the logcat screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr0Us.png)

[image]

Logcat says the error is in onCreate function but on seeing code I can't understand everything looks fine.
Need help please.

Comment: you should post your log as a text not as a screenshot buddy

Comment: Please refer to the duplicate linked at the top of your question. The required ID has a very specific format.

Answer (score 2):

In the logcat output, you can single out:

> Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Have you missed this line? This might be the problem. Just check it out.

So, this is the solution:

> < ListView android:id="@android:id/list" >

Comment: I tried with  changing the id of list view as "list" but the problem persists

Comment: @AshishPal Show new logs, probably there's another error.

Comment: @Ashish I've made my answer more specific. See if it works now!

Comment: problem solved thankx .[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050817/your-content-must-have-a-listview-whose-id-attribute-is-android-r-id-list?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @Ashish Cool! Upvote my answer if you prefer. Yes, the linked SO question has more details.